# How to add fading effect when you toggle css in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add fading effect function when it toggles css stlye attributes and adds classList .
JS:

```
function darkMode(){
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
}
function dropDown(){
    var options = document.getElementById("options")
    options.style.display == "block" ? options.style.display = "none" : 
    options.style.display = "block"; 
    options.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

css:

```
#options{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    background: var(--main-bg-color);
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 80px;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 9.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transition: ease-in-out .125s;
}
#options.active{
    top: 65px; 
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease-in-out .25s;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="profile-top" onclick="dropDown()">
                <div class="header-nav">
                    <p class="top-profile-name">
                        name
                    </p>
                    <img class="profile-image" src="..\img\img.png\">
                    <svg width="10" height="6" viewBox="0 0 10 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="dropdown-icon" data-v-49c8d0d2="">
                        <path d="M1 1L5 5L9 1" stroke="white" data-v-49c8d0d2=""></path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="top-profile-menu"  id="options">
                    <div class="setting-buttons">
                        <img class="setting-icons" src="..\img\settings.svg\">
                        <a class="profile-parameters">
                            settings
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="setting-buttons" onclick="darkMode()">
                        <img class="setting-icons" src="..\img\moon.svg\">
                        <a class="profile-parameters">
                            dark design
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="setting-buttons">
                        <img class="setting-icons" src="..\img\logout.svg\">
                        <a class="profile-parameters">
                            logout
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

here is full html css and js code at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/471spf9y/1/)
I have a div element, when you click it, the funcion(darkMode) toggles on, and changes css attribute `display: none;` to `display: block;` and addsClassLists, i've added transition attribute in css,but when displays change, transitions doesn't work. I want to make transition work, or somehow add js fade effect, without using jquery.

Comment: You do not have any class called `dark-mode` in your CSS ? am i missing something ?

Comment: I know, I'm working on it.
I want to fix function dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `visability: hidden;` and `visability: visible;` in second class